# Existence of smooth solutions to the heat equation with variable coefficients

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, heat-equation

> Consider $$\partial_{t} u - a  \partial_{x}^{2}u = f, $$ in $[0,1]\times [0,T]$,  where $a, f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}$ are smooth. Additionally, the initial data
> $$u(x,0) = u_{0} $$ is smooth and we further endow $u$ with boundary conditions $$u(0,t) = u(1,t).  $$

**Question:** How can you prove the existence of a smooth solution to this problem?

I have read somewhere that this follows from the theory of linear parabolic equations, but I don't know which theory exactly. I did see a proof in Evans for the homogeneous heat equation in $\mathbb{R}$ but that's about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to proceed would be to explicitly construct the solution to this equation (which is relatively simple since it's linear). To satisfy the periodicity condition on the interval $[0,1]$ one needs to expand the solution in a Fourier series. Following through with this procedure, one finds that the function given by

$$u(x,t)=\int_0^1 dy ~u_0(y)\Theta(x-y,t)+\int_0^1 dy\int_0^{t}dt' f(y,t')\Theta(x-y,t-t')~~,~~ t>0$$

satisfies the equation and the initial conditions. Here $\Theta(x,t)$ is a kernel with the properties
$$1.~~\Theta(x,t)\in C^\infty([0,1]\times(0,T])$$
$$2.~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\int_0^\infty \Theta(x,t)dx=1$$

Can you show properties 1. and 2. and replicate the proof of Evans?

> **HINT:**
> $$\Theta(x,t)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-4\pi^2 a n^2 t }e^{i2\pi n x}$$

Comment: Hang on: isn't this PDE a semilinear one and not linear? Since the coefficient $a$ depends on the independent variables $x$ and $t$. Perhaps I should have been more explicit in the statement of the problem

Comment: Never mind, misread it as a constant...

Comment: But I think I made a mistake classifying this as a semilinear problem; the PDE is still linear because $a$ is a function of only the independent variables. Shouldn't the technique you provided still work? Perhaps with some small modifications?

Comment: You can only generalize this solution to $a$ a function of $t$. Fully general $a$'s are not tractable. I've been thinking about how to produce an estimate on the solution to indirectly prove existence but I've yet to find a satisfactory argument for all $a$ positive and bounded. I've so far tried using Lax- Milgram for weak solutions.

Comment: How about if $a$ is only a function of $x$? I think this may be sufficient in my case!

Comment: I cannot construct an explicit solution, but I'll try for existence again when I have time.

Comment: Theorem 7.2 in Evans answers this question I believe. They set up a Galerkin scheme to prove that the general PDE $$u_{t} + Lu = f,$$ where $L$ is a linear elliptic differential operator, with initial data $g$ admits a smooth solution on $\bar{U} \times [0,T]$ where $U$ is an arbitrary open bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: yes, [I found something as well](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch6.pdf), here weak solutions are treated and classical solutions are established from a theorem due to Sobolev.